# How to implement below JQuery web chart Control in C# win form?

Tags: c#, charts

[image: Web Chart]

HI,
I have a chart control which was created by Jquery and Now i want to create the same Chart  control in C#.

Currently, I have done some thing like below,

[image: My C# Chart]

The problem is , at the X-Axis i need to get the year value like the web chart control.

When i change the x-axis value using

```
string[] array = new string[] {"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017" };

foreach (DataColumn dc in dtChartDataSource.Columns)
                {
                    //a series to the chart
                    if (chart.Series.FindByName(dc.ColumnName) == null)
                    {
                        series = dc.ColumnName;
                        chart.Series.Add(series);
                        chart.Series[series].ChartType = (SeriesChartType)intType;

                        chart.Series[series].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                    }
                    //Add data points to the series
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dtChartDataSource.Rows)
                    {
                        double dataPoint = 0;
                        double.TryParse(dr[dc.ColumnName].ToString(), out dataPoint);
                        DataPoint objDataPoint = new DataPoint() { YValues = new double[] { dataPoint } };
                        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(array[ivalue], dataPoint);
                    } 
                    ivalue++;
                }
```

How can achieve the same?
Please advise.

I could not able to insert images here due to my low credit points.

Comment: Got it finally, Thanks

Comment: If you don't have a question, please delete!

Comment: use of the below code piece i have solved the same,                                                                                         Mychart.Series[seriesName].Points.AddXY(CustomStringArray[ivalue++], dataPointsOfYaxis);